# Issue while importing the data from mysql to hbase using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

error message while importing the data from my mysql to HBase using sqoop. Here is my command

```
sqoop import --hbase-create-table  --hbase-table myemployee --column-family info --hbase-row-key empid --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/sampledb --table employee -m 1
```

Exception

```
15/08/25 15:01:33 INFO mapreduce.HBaseImportJob: Creating missing HBase table myemployee
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:222)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:264)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Hadoop version 2.6.0
HBase 1.0.1
Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6

Comment: Appears to be some jar issue. is your hbase classpath properly set?

Comment: @Shashi: I set this   HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.1/bin/hbase classpath` /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar  
Also checked   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032693/nosuchmethoderror-htabledescriptor-addfamily  
still no clue